# How to authenticate as admin, query and mutate Hasura in python?

Tags: python, authentication, graphql, hasura

I'm trying to find any documentation with examples to authenticate to hasura on heroku in python and query and mutate data, I couldn't find any info on this topic, can you guy please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you can do is send, just like in the other languages, a request to your hasura endpoint and add the header x-hasura-admin-secret and your secret key.

```
       {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'x-hasura-admin-secret': configuration.ACCESS_KEY,
            },
            url: 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/v1/graphql',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                query: mutation,
                variables: { userId, name, email, avatar },
            }),
        }
```

Comment: Your answer is useful l but I'm still not quite sure how to implement this in python. Thanks.

Comment: @AllexRadu you can try with https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/